# Color gradient in pheatmap to make close values more distinguishable

Tags: r, colors, visualization, pheatmap

How to make colors and values in the gradient bar of pheatmap more distinct? For example, it is important in my case to distinguish values 0.9 and 0.99. But pheatmap colors those values the same color.

```
library(MCMCglmm)
x=matrix(rtnorm(n = 100, lower = 0, upper = 1), nrow=10, ncol=10)
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
pheatmap::pheatmap(x, color = colfunc(10))
```

[image]